# How to add WMS legend in leaflet from Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms, symbology, legend

Can anyone explain me how I can include a legend within the layer control for any individual WMS layers in leaflet?

---

The wms service works fine. I just want  assign the symbol label to each layer of the group.

This is an example of my app:

[image]

My code is similar to the leaflet groupedlayercontrol plugin: https://github.com/ismyrnow/Leaflet.groupedlayercontrol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be other options at your disposal, however I will mention two options that you can explore to add a legend to your WMS on Geoserver.

You could always utilize the request `GetMap` which will allow you to make modification/changes to your layout properties. You can read more on the Geoserver webapage [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/advanced/wmsdecoration.html#decoration-types)

Another option I came across is github user: kartoza [webpage](https://github.com/kartoza/leaflet-wms-legend) were he provides a simple WMS legend plugin to use.

> This is a simple plugin for leaflet that will display a WMS GetLegendGraphic request result in a legend. At the moment the plugin is really, really simple in that is actually will display any image URI you pass it on initialisation. However that is enough to create a nice looking legend on your map like this:

[image]

Comment: There isn't anything linked to your code?

Comment: Hello whyzar. Before too I apologize for the way I put the question on the platform. It was the first I used this forum.
  I did what you told me about the first choice,and i used the service getLegendGraphic from Geoserver. Then i put the link generated by this service, before the layer code, like this: var groupedmaps={
"Qualificação do Espaço":
{"<img src='Link from Geoserver GetLegendgraphic ' height=...>Layer name":Data layer }; .  Thanks

Comment: If you use the layout option on the GetMap request, each tile contains a legend. Your typical map uses 12 tiles. That is a lot of legends. How do you configure geoserver to only return one legend instead returning a legend for each Tile?

Comment: That's a great question. I think it would be best if you created a new post with your exact question. Including what you have tried and what you searched and haven't been able to find an answer.